# Azure API MANAGEMENT - Api security

Tags: api, azure-api-management

in my company we are using azure api management.
I'm reading the microsoft doc and i'm focused on product and subscription. On 2 api i started to apply the product with related subscription (that i passed to my dev colleagues and they are using with our mobile app). On 99% of api we implemented jwt validation policy as security layer.

One or two api are exposed without subscription or jwt validations, as dev requirement.
I don't understand the subscription and their use. I would like to generate a subscription key specific for api without jwt policy, but i think is not the right way becouse the key will be hardcoded into our mobile app and can easily stolen i think.

here policy jwt:

```
        <validate-jwt header-name="Auth-token" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" clock-skew="600">
        <issuer-signing-keys>
            <key certificate-id="jwt" />
        </issuer-signing-keys>
    </validate-jwt>
```

There are some other method on api management to implement for this case? Or subscription is enough?

Answer (score 0):

As you said the subscription key will be hard coded and you also have manually rotate it .

Jwt with bearer tokens are a better way because the tokens have expiration dates this makes them better.

Azure active directory is also good if you want RBAC.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell) for further details.